# How to query MongoDB with specific request?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongodb-query

Currently I have 3 blog posts saved in my database and I want to retrieve the blog post based on its name.

Here is my database in MongoDB:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61de0e1562abb7ffd4089373"),
    name: 'learn-react',
    upvotes: 0,
    comments: []
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61de0e1562abb7ffd4089374"),
    name: 'learn-node',
    upvotes: 0,
    comments: []
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61de0e1562abb7ffd4089375"),
    name: 'my-thoughts-on-resumes',
    upvotes: 0,
    comments: []
  }
]
```

For instance, if I want to send a GET request to retrieve the 'learn-react' using the url: localhost:8000/articles/learn-react, how would I query the database? I only know how to retrieve all documents in the collection by using `db.find()` but how would i go about retrieving one particular blog post by its name in the url?

Comment: `findOne` is the short answer. This looks like it came from a Linkedin course. You can find some code in that regard on [github](https://github.com/tromgy/my-blog/blob/master/src/server.js)

Comment: @tromgy yes but the source code still produces an error for me

Comment: @MayurVaghasiya Hmm. I'm looking for a more dynamic query in which you're able to change query based on the article name

Comment: @Letscode, what kind of error do you see? Update your post with the details or create a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) you can  deconstructs an array field. then using [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) you can filter the documents !  Try this code it's help you !

```
db.getCollection('your collection').aggregate([  
  {
    $unwind: '$cource' //name of the array
  },
 {
    $match: { 'cource.name': 'learn-react' }
  },
]);
```

Comment: If my answer help you !, then accept it :)

Comment: How does this answer match the question?

Comment: @Letscode want to return particular object which match from array using `$unwind` deconstructs  the array and using `$match` filter the data